# ClassCastException when instantiating interface object

Tags: android

I have a class that extends LinearLayout. That class has an interface that gets implemented by the fragment that instantiates it to listen for click events. My problem is that in the LinearLayout class, I can't figure out how to instantiate the callback object.

```
public class SelectionView extends LinearLayout {

    OnSelectionClickedListener mCallback;
    LinearLayout mSelection;

    public interface OnSelectionClickedListener {
        void onSelected(SelectionView view);
    }

    public SelectionView (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void init () {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        final LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.selection, this);

        mSelection = (LinearLayout) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.selection_container);
        mCallback = (SelectionClickedListener) this;

        // ...
}
```

The error I get is on the very last line:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.mysite.myapp.SelectionView cannot be cast to
>   com.mysite.myapp.SelectionView$OnSelectionClickedListener

I've tried a few other `Context` objects instead of `this` but I always have some variation on the `ClassCastException` error. What do I need to do in order to correct this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mCallback = (SelectionClickedListener) this;
```

`this` is a `SelectionView`. `SelectionView` does not implement its own `SelectionClickedListener` interface.

> I've tried a few other Context objects instead of this

`this` is not a `Context`. `this` is a `SelectionView`.

> That class has an interface that gets implemented by the fragment that instantiates it to listen for click events.

A fragment is not a `Context`. There is no `Context` object that will be your fragment.

> What do I need to do in order to correct this?

Step #1: Add a `setOnSelectionClickedListener()` method to `SelectionView`, taking a `SelectionClickedListener` object as a parameter. Use this to populate your `mCallback` field.

Step #2: Have your fragment call `setOnSelectionClickedListener()`, supplying its `SelectionClickedListener`. If the fragment itself is implementing `SelectionClickedListener`, then *in a method in the fragment*, `this` is a `SelectionClickedListener`, and so you could call `setOnSelectionClickedListener(this)`.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. It's very helpful. I'm stuck trying to implement this. If you don't mind, could you look at the edit to my OP? Thanks again! (great book, btw).

Comment: @Alex: Your error message does not match the code. It refers to `OnSportSelectionClickedListener` (which you don't show) and `OnClickListener` (presumably `View.OnClickListener`, which you don't seem to use here). Are you sure this crash is from the code in your edit? Also, thanks for the kind words!

Comment: Sorry, that should have said `OnSelectionClickedListener`. Yes, it is from the code I posted (although there is quite a bit left out, but nothing that should matter here). I guess I need to think about it a bit more. Thanks again.

Comment: @Alex: I am short on sleep. You are calling `setOnClickListener()` on `selection`, not `setOnSelectionClickedListener()`.

Comment: Ack! Thanks a million for your help. I'm with you on the lack of sleep.